# QuickOSM does not return results

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, query, overpass-api, quickosm

I'm trying to use the QuickOSM plugin so I can automate the search of addresses and creation of layers. Right now I'm just trying with one address using the key -> addr:street "Bäckerstr." And the key addr:housenumber "10". After running the query I get the message "Succesful query, but no result".
This is the generated query that runs when I click on show query.

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:münchen}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["addr:street"="bäckerstr. "]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
    way["addr:street"="bäckerstr. "]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
    relation["addr:street"="bäckerstr. "]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

Comment: Have you made sure there are any objects to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the full name of the street: `Bäckerstraße`, as the street is tagged in OSM, instead of `bäckerstr.`

To look for `bäckerstr`, you must perform a search query that 1) truncates and 2) ignores case (upper/lower case). To truncate, use `~` instead of `=`, to ignore case, add `,i`. Be aware **not** to include the point in the query. The query then looks like this:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:München}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["addr:street"~"bäckerstr",i]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
    way["addr:street"~"bäckerstr",i]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
    relation["addr:street"~"bäckerstr",i]["addr:housenumber"="10"](area.area_0);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

[image]

The easier alternative is to search for the exact name `Bäckerstraße`:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["addr:street"="Bäckerstraße"]["addr:housenumber"="10"]( {{bbox}});
    way["addr:street"="Bäckerstraße"]["addr:housenumber"="10"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["addr:street"="Bäckerstraße"]["addr:housenumber"="10"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it worked.

Comment: See updated answer as well with truncating/ignore case